# browser returning local computer with 404

Tags: browser, windows-server-2012, url

(I've phrased the question as best I can - I fear its still not good)

I'm using Windows Server 2012, and being new to network management I can't  work out what I've done wrong.

The symptoms of my problem are:
* If I try access google.com (for example) from Internet explorer, the message *"The requested URL /server.localdomain-GET was not found on this server"* is returned.

I would expect the URL to show "google.com" which makes me think there is an incorrect setting on the server.  I have looked but can't find any solutions so far.  We do have an IIS service site which might have a setting messing up but i don't think that is it.

Also this is not specific to only the browser.  It is affecting other programs trying to connect to urls.

Comment: Yes, your question is not the best. First let us know how are you connected to the WS2012? RDP? Direct console connection? Did you perform any network troubleshooting? Edit you question with ipconfig information. Can you ping the default gateway? Does DNS work? I would suggest you go through the [Microsoft Virtual Academy](https://mva.microsoft.com/search/SearchResults.aspx#!prod=Windows%20Server&prodv=Windows%20Server%202012%20R2&level=100&lang=1033) - I have set the link for Windows Server, Beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I postulate there are a number of issues contributing to this error, the most likely being -

1. An issue with the DNS server the machine is configured to use - I'm guessing its not returning valid answers.   The "Search Domain" is then being consulted, and a wildcard answe in one of the search domains is returning a pointer to a local web server which is badly configured.
2. Its possible that there is a transparent proxy (and/or) transparent redirection of requests taking place, again pointing to the local server.

There are some things you can do to try and narrow down the problem field -

1. If you open a command window and ping google.com, what IP address is returned ?  (My guess is that it will be a local IP).
2. What happens if you change the nameservers to 8.8.8.8 and repeat the same command (If this works, the core problem is a misconfigured nameserver, if it doesn't the problem is elsewhere)
3. What happens when you do a traceroute to google.com ?  Does it go through many hops to Googles server, or does it terminate in your network ?

Comment: Turns out to be a mix of Transparent proxy and DNS blocking with bad settings.